# Using virt-manager with seahorse instead of ssh-askpass?

Tags: ssh-keys, ssh-agent, virt-manager

On my Arch Linux virt-manager can not connect remote ssh and tells about installing ssh-askpass. As I wan't to use the gnome default seahorse, I was looking for a solution which I didn't find on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What binary is invoked depends on the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable. You can set it to your seahorse askpass in you rc files, instead of linking on to the other.

```
export SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/seahorse/seahorse-ssh-askpass
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply made a link from seahorse-ssh-askpass to ssh-askpass:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/seahorse/seahorse-ssh-askpass /usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass
```